# Doubt regarding PCA

Tags: pca, dataset, dimensionality-reduction

I have 5 different independent variables, lets name 1 to 5. The 3rd IV has 10 sub-variables under it and 4th IV has 11 sub-variables in it. Whereas other 3 IV's have just two sub-variables (questionnaires). So the method I want use to have less number of IV's is 
1) PCA on 3rd and 4th IV
2) Consolidate other variables (with just 2 underlying sub-variables) based on the value of Cronbach alpha. (combining 1.1 & 1.2 to have just 1, combining 2.1 & 2.2 and 5.1 &5.2). By combining I meant average.

Q1) Is this method valid. Is it okay to do PCA on some of IV's which has a large number of sub-variables and simple averaging on other IV's which has a low number of sub-variables?
2) How do I use factor values to find out component values?
3) initial scale for all these 5 IV's were 5 points Likert scale ranging between 1-5, now if I form component values for each respondent, it is appearing in decimals (ex: 1.789, 2.154, ..). how do I bring PCA conducted IV's and averaged Iv's into same scale?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the PCA?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to reduce the dimensions of 3rd and 4th IV's which has 10 and 11 subfactors respectively. So is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, @Madhu writes:

> Well, I was hoping to reduce the dimensions of 3rd and 4th IV's which
>   has 10 and 11 subfactors respectively. So is it possible?

In that case, I would do either PCA on just those factors, separately, or some sort of two stage process.